# Collapse isn't working on Bootstrap's mobile NavBar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The mobile dropdown menu doesn't appear when I click the button. Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/k5g2d4L1/ (resize window to active mobile dropdown button). Thank you in advance for your help!

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
      <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
     <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
   </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.trevessu.com"> Trevessu </a>
</div> 
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
            <li class=""> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
            <li class=""> <a href="#">Su di Noi</a> </li>
            <li class=""> <a href="#">Progetti</a> </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Add jQuery to your source, as bootstrap requires jQuery. [***DEMO***](https://jsfiddle.net/k5g2d4L1/1/)

Comment: If you look at the jsfiddle sample you can see the jquery has been added.

Comment: Yeah, but you have added it after `bootstrap.min.js`. `jquery.min.js` should be added single time before it.

Comment: Also, **Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3**

Comment: @ParkashKumar Your sample is working but I've not understood what's the jquery your have add on.

Comment: There are couple of problems in your code. i- You are adding jQuery after bootstrap. ii- You are adding jQuery twice. iii- bootstrap requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3.

Comment: Should I add this as answer, so that it may be useful for other in future?

Comment: @ParkashKumar Yes as I can sign it as Right! The problem was that I've included 1.8 and 3.00 version, now I've included 1.11 and it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems in your [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/k5g2d4L1/).

1. You are adding `jquery` library after `bootstrap`, `jquery` should be added first, because `bootstrap` requires `jquery` to initialize.
2. You are adding `jquery` twice (`1.8.1` & `3.0.0`), it should be added once.
3. `bootstrap` requires `jquery` version `1.9.1` or higher, but lower than version `3`, therefore, you should either use `1.10.1` or `1.11.0`

[**DEMO using 1.10.1**](https://jsfiddle.net/p7d906fy/)
[**DEMO using 1.11.0**](https://jsfiddle.net/51aadfmp/)